# Podrían apoyarme con django con un error en un template genérico TypeError: get_context_data()

Tags: django, django-views

Tengo duda en como hacer el proceso de generar contexto en un template genérico
Este es el error que me aparece:

line 133, in get
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
TypeError: get_context_data() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'request'

El código de mi documento views es este:

```
from .forms import UserCreationFormWithEmail, ProfileForm, EmailForm
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django import forms
from .models import Profile
from products.utils import cookieCart, cartData, guestOrder
from products.models import OrderItem

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'registration/profile_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *kwargs, request):
        data = cartData(request)
        cartItems = data['cartItems']
        user_orderitem = OrderItem.objects.order_by('-date_added').filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        orderitems = user_orderitem

        context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(*kwargs) 
        context['cartItems'] = self.get_action(request)
        context['orderitems'] = self.get_action()
        return context

    def get_object(self):
       # recuperar el objeto que se va editar
        profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user)
        return profile
```

Comment: Como te indica el error te falta 1 dato requerido, seria de mucha ayuda si colocaras el error que te esta enviando pero completo

Comment: Hola Kevin según yo no debería de ir el parametro request en el def get_context_data() seria get_context_data(self, **kwargs): y para el request lo sacas como self.request

Comment: Como dice @Raiganfast el método `get_context_data` no recibe ningún parámetro posicional llamado `request`.

Comment: lo solucioné con un:

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        data = cartData(self.request)
        cartItems = data['cartItems']
        context['cartItems'] = cartItems
        return context

Answer (score 0):

lo solucioné con un:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
    data = cartData(self.request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    context['cartItems'] = cartItems
    return context
```